# increment and decrement with cout in C++

Tags: c++, increment, cout, decrement

I'm new to C++ and study the increment and decrement operators.
So I tried this example:

```
    int x = 4;    
    cout << ++x << "    " << x++ << "    " << x++ << endl << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
```

It returns this *weird* output on C++ .NET and QtCreator and 5 online C++ compilers:

```
7    5    4

7
```

The *weird* thing is that I expect something like this:

```
5    5    6

7
```

Can you explain what happens?

Comment: When you put multiple `++` on the same line with no sequence points, the compiler isn't required to do things in any particular order.

Comment: @MarkRansom || Can you explain more

Comment: Google around a bit. This question is asked just about every week.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please notice that `cout << x++ << ++x;` is just another notation for:

```
operator<<( operator<< (cout, x++), ++x);
```

The **order** in which your **x++** and **++x** statements are evaluated is **undefined**, so is the effect of your code.

Even if it seems to happens from right to left in your particular examples, you should **not** rely on that by any means.

Just make another experiment by using multiple statements as:

```
cout << ++x << " ";
cout << x++ << " ";
cout << x++ << endl;
```

The solution to your problem is:

**Never** write **code** which results in **undefined** behaviour! :)

Comment: How can I define the statements order?

Comment: I'm understand I can use multiple statements but I need to know how the compiler execute my example.

Comment: @AliOsm Learning what the compiler does with unspecified code is a false economy. It may be interesting, but the knowledge is almost worthless because you cannot count on it to remain the same. Your compiler may give one number, your neighbour's another, and your uncle Bob may get a third number. The compiler can literally do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 2):

The result is undefined for your example. This is because the order of evaluation of `x++` or `++x` in a line are undefined.

In short if you want predictable behaviour when using
operator ++ then the variable it is applied to should only appear once
in the expression being evaluated.

Comment: You mean if the compiler see the ++ operator more than 1 time in the same line don't make priorities and run it only?

Comment: @AliOsm..it means if the compiler sees ++ operator more than once it is not known in which order it will compute....

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called undefined beehive, and is dependent on what compiler you use, to better understand this you have to know computer architecture and how compiler works:

```
cout << x++ << hello << x++ << endl
```

one compiler can convert this sequence to binary sequence, that would do following

```
increment x 
print x
print hello
increment x
print x
print endl
```

while second compiler can do it as following

```
print x
increment x
print hello
print x
increment x
print endl
```

third one can do it as following

```
print x
print hello
print x
print endl
increment x
```

and forth one can do following

```
increment x
print x
print hello
print x
print endl
```

your best bet to sort this issue is:

```
x++;
cout << x << hello;
x++;
cout << x << endl;
```

Comment: I'm use C++ on .NET framework, and I need to know how the compiler execute my example and print that output.

Comment: That is the problem I do not know I think Visual Studio is going backward. Put `endl` onto the stack increment x, put hello onto the stack, increment x put it onto the stack, at the end print it.