# Different output debug vs release

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { 
public: 
    A() { a.a = a.b = 1; }
    struct { int a, b; } a;
    int b(void);
};
int A::b(void) {
    int x = a.a; a.a = a.b; a.b = x; return x;
}
int main(void) { 
    A a;
    a.a.a = 0;
    a.b();
    cout << a.b() << a.a.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting different result when running in debug mode and in release mode. In release mode i get 11, while in debug mode i get 10. What is causing this output difference? I'm using visual studio 2017.

Comment: `cout << a.b() << a.a.b << endl;` smells like undefined behavior to me. It'd be like `cout << i++ << i;` which I believe we have a question on already. Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: Here are two example questions with good explanatory answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33445796/2602718), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214611/2602718). It looks like convention here is to use the sequence points question as the dupe target though.

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undefined behavior here

```
cout << a.b() << a.a.b << endl;
```

The function modifies `a.a.b` and you read from it too. The compiler can change the other however it wants.

Comment: This changed in C++17. You may not get what you expect, but the behaviour is no longer undefined.