# What is the possible reason for this output in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

**I have just typed a peace of code but I am getting weird result , so what can be the possible reason?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 5;
    cout << a++ << endl << ++a << endl;
    cout << ++b << endl << b++;
    return 0;
}
```

> EXPECTED OUTPUT

> ```
>             5
>             7
>             6
>             6
> ```

> OUTPUT I AM GETTING

> ```
>             6                                                                                                                                             
>             7                                                                                                                                             
>             7                                                                                                                                             
>             5
> ```

Comment: _Undefined behavior_ may be? No need in YELLING by the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214611/unexpected-order-of-evaluation-compiler-bug and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445796/increment-and-decrement-with-cout-in-c talk about it.